# Subreport isn't shown when exported to pdf, xls or doc

Tags: java, export, jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I have a main report and a subreport working nice. The subreport is printed in the summary band. My problem is when I export the report. The subreport is invisible, only main report is presented. I export to pdf, xls and doc. In all 3 formats is the same.

Comment: I principle, saving your report in any format should work fine especially since your report is displayed correctly. Check your iReport installation and upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Can you post your report? May be light version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you export in your laptop?. if not. you must delete path folder in xml tab before.